# Google sheets Query not returning values

Tags: google-sheets, string-formatting, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I have the following Query:

=QUERY('Fleury Braz Leme'!$A$31:$I$55;"select H, I, F, E where G = '"&I39&"'")

[image]

Some values from column E are being returned, but others are not. As you can see in the case below/above, on that linked sheet, there are corresponding values:

[image]

What can I do to correct it?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(TO_TEXT('Fleury Braz Leme'!$A$31:$I$55);
 "select Col8, Col9, Col6, Col5 
  where Col7 = '"&I39&"'"))
```